# How to keep user logged in for next instance

Tags: .net, winforms, cefsharp

I have a question about how to keep user logged in for next instance.

Tried gmail - works fine, but I want to use **web.whatsapp.com.** I'm able to sign in with my phone, but for next instance I have to log in again.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

**My test code:**

```
Public Sub New()

Dim settings As New CefSettings()
settings.CachePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\CEF"
CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(settings)
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("persist_session_cookies", "1")

InitializeComponent()

WB = New ChromiumWebBrowser("web.whatsapp.com") With {
.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        }
Me.Controls.Add(WB)

End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: What version are you using? If `Gmail` works then it's unlikely a bug in `CefSharp`, see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#cefsharp-vs-chromium-embedded-frameworkcef

Comment: Use `--cache-path` command line arg to specify cache path

Comment: Hi, I'm using version 55. Could you please give me example of using this command?